# How do I create a singleton element in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I want to create an element that a user can only instantiate once.

So far the best I can think of doing is defining the element within an anonymous function and throwing an error when I find the element already exists.  Is there a way so it just rejects being created?

```
(function(){
  var singleton = false;
  Polymer({
   is:'my-singleton',
   created:function(){
    if(singleton) {
     throw new Error ('only one my-singleton should be created');
    }
    singleton = this;
   }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seems that there is an undocumented `remove()` function for elements. I just moved the code previously to the `attached` function, and keep a variable which notes if I have been made active or not.

```
(function(){
  var singleton = false;
  Polymer({
   is:'my-singleton',
   attached:function(){
    if(singleton) {
     this.isActive = false;
     this.remove();
    } else {
     singleton = true;
     this.isActive = true;
     // remainder of element initialization
    }
  },
  detached:function() {
   if(this.isActive) singleton = false;
  }
 });
})();
```

This seems to work very well.

Comment: I'm trying to create a element that can only be instantiated once but that once element is referenced by multiple other elements. Is that what you are trying to do? If so can you please elaborate on the solution you went with.

Comment: @DaleSnowdon That's exactly what this element does.  It removes itself if one is already there.  Its the basis of a router I created but no longer use, see https://github.com/akc42/akc-router.  I also use a pattern where there a multiple copies of elements, but they all access the same data. See https://github.com/akc42/akc-meta as an example (again I don't use any more as its too generic as my shared data is mostly stuff read from a database)

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to restrict the number of `<my-singleton>` on the page, or just have a singleton 'state'?

To share a singleton state/service between multiple element instances you can do this:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // singleton shared connection between all instances of rg-signalr
    var singletonState = {
        counter: 0
    };

    Polymer({
        is: 'my-element-using-singleton-state',

        attached() {
            singletonState.counter++;
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: No, shared state is easy.  I want only one element.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. But can you give me more detail how `singletonState ` is kept as single state?